# View attachment thumbnail of each post in a category list in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, attachment

this is what i would like to do...
In my site,each post can have several pictures, but also each post has an attached picture called: thumbnail {name of my post}, this specific picture was attached to the post with the multimedia gallery, and the objective of this picture is to appear in the category list.

```
<article>
    <p class="the-picture"><img src="url-of-the-picture" /></a>
    <p class="the-post-title"><a href="url-of-the-post">The post title</a></p>
    <p class="the-post-excerpt">The post excerpt</p>
</article>
```

So basically that's what i want to do, Maybe using get_post() but i can't figure out how to do it from outside the post.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... here is what I found so far:
The following code will get me the category i'm on:

```
global $wp_query;
global $wpdb;
$cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
```

So, now with the category i can list all the posts:

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 'category' => $_GET[ 'cat' ] ) );
```

And for each post i can do this:

```
$attachment_id = $wpdb->get_var('
    SELECT ID 
    FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' 
    WHERE post_parent = "' . $record->ID . '" AND post_status = "inherit" AND post_type="attachment" AND post_title LIKE "thumb%" 
    ORDER BY post_date DESC 
    LIMIT 1');
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, array( 90, 117 ) );
$the_icon = '<img src="' . $thumb[0] . '" width="' . $thumb[1] . '" height="' . $thumb[2] . '" />';
```

So, basically what i'm doing is looking for the ID of the child post which is marked as the thumbnail of the post and retrieving its information into $thumb. The answer that [moraleida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001109/moraleida) gave me was a nice start for my research. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the defaul post thumbnails functions instead of naming the image after the post.

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Then on the editor you'll be able to select which image is the default "featured" image. To display the images on the loop you'll use either [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) or [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) like this:

```
<p class="the-picture"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></p>
```

**EDIT:**

if you can't use the default thumbs functionalilty, maybe you can create another post field with [add_meta_box();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and include it in every post save with [update_post_meta();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).

This way you'll have a permanent value on your DB to tell you which thumb to use on the cat list, and you'll be able to retrieve it with [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) on category.php like this:

```
<p class="the-picture"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $cat_picture, true); ?></p>
```

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is that each post can have several thumbnails and that's the reason why i'm using a specific thumbnail, because in the category list i need to be able to be specific with the picture to be displayed. Using that i guess the post can have a different thumbnail than the one i choose.

Comment: I don't really get it, but if you need to have one specific thumb for each post, and it can't be the default thumb, maybe the way to do it is adding a custom meta-box and setting it there. Edited the answer to fit.